Error when trying to deploy a war-File on Openshift using tomcat 9
I have a java war-File which i want to deploy on Openshift using tomcat 9.
I want to do this via the openshift console

Log in to my Openshift:
oc login --token=sha256~O_SDFSDFJp0sD3Q5vTmo --server=https://my-openshift-server.com:6443

Switch to my project:
oc project my-oc-project

Create a new application using a Tomcat 9 image:
oc new-app tomcat:9.0~https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-java-container.git --name=my-tomcat-app

Create my build configuration which includes my war-File.
oc start-build my-tomcat-app --from-file=C:\temp\Java\myApp.war


The first 3 Steps run without any errors.
But at my 4th step i get this error:
Error from server (NotFound): buildconfigs.build.openshift.io "my-tomcat-app" not found

What did i do wrong?
Thanks in advance!
